# pthread_create -How can I create single thread and call it in the loop when needed

Tags: c, pthreads

I have looking examples with pthread_create, but all examples are very similar: they call pthread_create in while or for loop so the many threads are created. How can I achieve to create just one thread before loop and then to call it in the loop when needed? Every time when I call it it goes into function and execute its work there.

Thx

Comment: You create it once and you need some synchronization mechanism (thread is ready to do work or it's busy etc) if you want to create just one thread and reuse whenever you have some work for it to do.

Comment: For example ? Which mechanism and how to use it in this context? How can I call this thread whenever I have some work for it to do?

Comment: What on earth does "call it" mean?!

Comment: Every time when I call this single created thread it goes into function and executes its work there

Comment: Threads means Light weight process, once it is created means in will start run automatically. Threads are independent processes, scheduled by kernel, you cant schedule them. For your case you need to go with functions!

Comment: Give some hint about what you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Every time when I call it it goes into function and execute its work
>   there

You can not do it like that. When ever you create a thread with `pthread_create` successfully, the thread function starts executing in parallel. and **after the function returns, the thread is terminated**.

If you need to `'call'` the thread function again, you have to create another thread.

If your requirement is to handle packets received from server, you may use the following path:

- Receive `Packet`
- create a thread with a function to process the `Packet` and pass `Packet` to it. (read about parameters to thread function).
- go to 1st step.

The thread function will process your packet while you can receive the next packet from server.

Comment: Is the thread terminated by default after the function executes or I must tell that explicitly? (how?) Is there maybe another way how can I achieve this? I have server and many clients. Server is sending packets to the clients and when clients are responding to the server I want to have separate thread to process those responses.

Comment: generally threads are terminated automatically when the function ends, this is how your programs terminates after returning from main. You can explicitly `cancel` a thread in between. I am updating my answer to addres your server client situation.

Comment: I done it on your way for the first time, but I thought that is not good to call the pthread_create every time when the response is received. So what happens when I return from the function with variables ? I suppose I must have some global variable when I store my information from thread function because I terminated thread every time? And last question: should I cancel thread in my function or it will terminate for sure? Can I use pthread_detach(pthread_self()) in function?

Comment: If your thread function returns, your thread will be terminated for sure. For your last question, read about join-able threads, `pthread_join` and `pthread_detach`. Thread is for asynchronous processing, understand that, if you use normal function, you have to wait for it to return before looping, the call to function is blocking the execution. but if you use thread, the function will be executed in parallel and you can proceed with your code. To get return value from your thread function, you need to join the thread by its thread id somewhere.